# Verify SUM of table records on INSERT

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that keeps track of transactions for various accounts:

**AccountTransactions**

```
AccountTransactionID int NOT NULL (PK) 
AccountID int NOT NULL (FK) 
Amount decimal NOT NULL
```

Upon inserting a record with a negative amount into this table, I need to verify that the SUM of the amount column for the specified account is greater than zero.  If the new record will cause this SUM to fall below zero, the record should not be inserted.

For example, if I have the following records, inserting an amount of -8.00 for `AccountID` 5 should not be allowed:

```
AccountTransactionID     AccountID     Amount
---------------------------------------------
1                        5             10.00
2                        6             15.00
3                        5             -3.00
```

What is the best method to accomplish this?  Check constraint, trigger, or just check for this condition in a stored procedure?

Comment: What behavior do you want to happen when the amount is not allowed?

Comment: It can raise an error.  I have logic in my application so that this condition should never even reach the database, but I want of a level of protection at the data layer as well.

Comment: If the accountID is one of the parameters of your proc, I would just use a sub query that sums the current value (before insert) then do the comparison as a condition of your where clause.  If the records affected are less than 1, then you can throw an appropriate exception.  I am sure there are other ways to do it, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple check:

```
DECLARE @TheSum decimal(18,2)

SET @TheSum = (SELECT SUM(MyCol) FROM MyTable WHERE AccountID = @SomeParameter)

If @TheSum > 0 
  BEGIN
    --do your insert
  END
...
```

Comment: This introduces a race condition. Another process could decrease the sum between the `set` statement and the `insert`.

Comment: Could using a transaction mitigate the race condition?

Comment: a transaction with an appropriate isolation level will help cut down on this issue of concurrent transactions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Yes a transaction at "repeatable read" or "serializable" would fix that.  In addition this answer checks the sum before the addition, it should probably check the sum after the transaction instead. The goal is to prevent negative sums from appearing, not to prevent additions to negative sums.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `where` clause to your insert:

```
insert  YourTable
        (AccountID, Amount)
select  @AccountID, @Amount
where   0 <= 
        (
        select  @Amount + sum(Amount) 
        from    YourTable 
        where   AccountID = @AccountID
        )
```

Comment: Check your `Where` clause this looks to be incorrect, why are you assigning the AccountID to @Amount?